# Windows 10 showing full file size in destination before copy has finished

Tags: windows, file-io, registry, ntfs

When copying a large file (say 8GB) the destination file shows as 8GB immediately, before the file has finished copying.

This is causing problems with a third party software that is polling the file waiting for the full size to be copied.

Is there a way to change this behavior so the file system reports the file size incrementally as it is being copied?

Additional info:

The Cygwin "cp" command seems to solve the problem, but I need a native Windows solution

This behavior can be seen when using the cmd prompt "copy" command and when using File Explorer to copy files

Windows 10 Version 1909 (OS Build 19363.535)